# How to select unquoted html attribute values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple `select` element which I am appending dynamically to a `form`
from a hidden field. I have escaped the spaces in the element

This is my hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="field1" name="field1" value="<select id=multipleselectid1 name=multipleselectid1 multiple><option value=All&nbsp;Balance&nbsp;Types>All Balance Types</option><option value=010>010 - Opening Ledger Balance</option><option value=011>011 - Average Opening Ledger MTD</option></select>" />
```

I want to select the first value by default i.e `value="All&nbsp;Balance&nbsp;Types"`

This is my code to select the first value

```
var elevalue='All Balance Types';// -------> This doesn't work
var arr1 = elevalue.trim().split('\,');
$('#multipleselectid1').val(arr1);
```

But this value is not getting selected

I also implemented a test code to check whether other values are getting selected or not. So I tried this code

```
var elementvalue='010,011'; //-----------> This works
var arr = elementvalue.trim().split('\,');
$('#multipleselectid1').val(arr);
```

This snippet is working

**Why is only the first value not getting selected?**

This is the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/y8djzb88/)** to above example

Comment: value in input element are interpreted like string

Comment: Did you try with `var elevalue='All&nbsp;Balance&nbsp;Types'` instead of `"All Balance Types"`?

Comment: @Roque Yes but still not working

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. Storing HTML within the attribute of another HTML element is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `&nbsp;` from value in selectbox and add single quote in value:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myform').append($('#field1').val());
   var elementvalue='All Balance Types'; //-----------> This works
   var arr = elementvalue.trim().split('\,');
   $('#multipleselectid1').val(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="field1" name="field1" value="<select id=multipleselectid1 name=multipleselectid1 multiple><option value='All Balance Types'>All Balance Types</option><option value=010>010 - Opening Ledger Balance</option><option value=011>011 - Average Opening Ledger MTD</option></select>" />

<form id="myform">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make the fiddle work by wrapping the `value` attribute with single quotes, and dropping in double quotes where they're supposed to be in the html.

However, I would *highly* suggest staying far away from appending string html from one part of the page to another.  It's very susceptible to XSS attacks.

```
<input type="hidden" id="field1" name="field1" value='<select id="multipleselectid1" name="multipleselectid1" multiple><option value="All Balance Types">All Balance Types</option><option value="010">010 - Opening Ledger Balance</option><option value="011">011 - Average Opening Ledger MTD</option></select>' />
```